# Compiling a jar file with other class files on mac(command: javac -cp ".;queue.jar" *.java)?

Tags: java, jar

I tried these command, but it doesn't seem to find the sevral classes that are related to the this program.

I've tried

```
javac -cp ".;queue.jar" *.java
```

and

```
javac -cp "/"pathName/queue.jar" *.java
```

when I used the first one this is what it gives me.

Even though `CD`, `KeyedItem`, `QueueInterface`, and other classes that it complains about.  `CD`, `KeyedItem`, and `QueueInterface` is `.class` file.

```
BSTDriver.java:25: error: cannot find symbol
   private static CD[] readMusic(String fileName)
                  ^
  symbol:   class CD
  location: class BSTDriver
BinarySearchTree.java:11: error: cannot find symbol
   public KeyedItem retrieve(Comparable searchKey) 
          ^
  symbol:   class KeyedItem
  location: class BinarySearchTree
BinarySearchTree.java:46: error: cannot find symbol
   public void insert(KeyedItem item) throws TreeException
                      ^
  symbol:   class KeyedItem
  location: class BinarySearchTree
BinarySearchTree.java:58: error: cannot find symbol
   protected KeyedItem retrieveItem(TreeNode tNode, Comparable searchKey)
             ^
  symbol:   class KeyedItem
  location: class BinarySearchTree
BinarySearchTree.java:92: error: cannot find symbol
   protected TreeNode insertItem(TreeNode tNode, KeyedItem item) throws TreeException
                                                 ^
  symbol:   class KeyedItem
  location: class BinarySearchTree
BinarySearchTree.java:292: error: cannot find symbol
   protected KeyedItem findLeftmost(TreeNode tNode)  
             ^
  symbol:   class KeyedItem
  location: class BinarySearchTree
SearchTreeInterface.java:34: error: cannot find symbol
   public void insert(KeyedItem item) throws TreeException;
                      ^
  symbol:   class KeyedItem
  location: interface SearchTreeInterface
SearchTreeInterface.java:49: error: cannot find symbol
   public KeyedItem retrieve(Comparable searchKey);
          ^
  symbol:   class KeyedItem
  location: interface SearchTreeInterface
BinaryTreeIterator.java:1: error: package queue does not exist
import queue.*;
^
BinaryTreeIterator.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
   private QueueInterface items;       
           ^
  symbol:   class QueueInterface
  location: class BinaryTreeIterator
BSTDriver.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
    CD[] cds = CD.readMusic(args);
    ^
  symbol:   class CD
  location: class BSTDriver
BSTDriver.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
    CD[] cds = CD.readMusic(args);
               ^
  symbol:   variable CD
  location: class BSTDriver
BSTDriver.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
    BinarySeachTree bst = new BinarySearchTree();
    ^
  symbol:   class BinarySeachTree
  location: class BSTDriver
BSTDriver.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
        for(Cd c: cds)
            ^
  symbol:   class Cd
  location: class BSTDriver
BSTDriver.java:27: error: cannot find symbol
      FileIO file = new FileIO(fileName, FileIO.FOR_READING);
      ^
  symbol:   class FileIO
  location: class BSTDriver
BSTDriver.java:27: error: cannot find symbol
      FileIO file = new FileIO(fileName, FileIO.FOR_READING);
                        ^
  symbol:   class FileIO
  location: class BSTDriver
BSTDriver.java:27: error: cannot find symbol
      FileIO file = new FileIO(fileName, FileIO.FOR_READING);
                                         ^
  symbol:   variable FileIO
  location: class BSTDriver
BSTDriver.java:29: error: cannot find symbol
      ArrayList<CD> cds = new ArrayList<CD>();
                ^
  symbol:   class CD
  location: class BSTDriver
BSTDriver.java:29: error: cannot find symbol
      ArrayList<CD> cds = new ArrayList<CD>();
                                        ^
  symbol:   class CD
  location: class BSTDriver
BSTDriver.java:36: error: cannot find symbol
         CD cd = new CD(title, str, year, rating, numTracks);
         ^
  symbol:   class CD
  location: class BSTDriver
BSTDriver.java:36: error: cannot find symbol
         CD cd = new CD(title, str, year, rating, numTracks);
                     ^
  symbol:   class CD
  location: class BSTDriver
BSTDriver.java:54: error: cannot find symbol
      CD[] cds_array = new CD[cds.size()];
      ^
  symbol:   class CD
  location: class BSTDriver
BSTDriver.java:54: error: cannot find symbol
      CD[] cds_array = new CD[cds.size()];
                           ^
  symbol:   class CD
  location: class BSTDriver
BSTDriver.java:56: error: cannot find symbol
      for(CD cd : cds)
          ^
  symbol:   class CD
  location: class BSTDriver
BinarySearchTree.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
        KeyedItem item = retrieveItem(getRootNode(),"Asphyx");
        ^
  symbol:   class KeyedItem
  location: class BinarySearchTree
BinarySearchTree.java:38: error: cannot find symbol
            it =(KeyedItem) it.next();
                 ^
  symbol:   class KeyedItem
  location: class BinarySearchTree
BinarySearchTree.java:62: error: cannot find symbol
      KeyedItem treeItem;
      ^
  symbol:   class KeyedItem
  location: class BinarySearchTree
BinarySearchTree.java:70: error: cannot find symbol
         KeyedItem nodeItem = (KeyedItem) tNode.getItem();
         ^
  symbol:   class KeyedItem
  location: class BinarySearchTree
BinarySearchTree.java:70: error: cannot find symbol
         KeyedItem nodeItem = (KeyedItem) tNode.getItem();
                               ^
  symbol:   class KeyedItem
  location: class BinarySearchTree
BinarySearchTree.java:104: error: cannot find symbol
      KeyedItem nodeItem = (KeyedItem)tNode.getItem();
      ^
  symbol:   class KeyedItem
  location: class BinarySearchTree
BinarySearchTree.java:104: error: cannot find symbol
      KeyedItem nodeItem = (KeyedItem)tNode.getItem();
                            ^
  symbol:   class KeyedItem
  location: class BinarySearchTree
BinarySearchTree.java:137: error: cannot find symbol
      KeyedItem nodeItem = (KeyedItem)tNode.getItem();
      ^
  symbol:   class KeyedItem
  location: class BinarySearchTree
BinarySearchTree.java:137: error: cannot find symbol
      KeyedItem nodeItem = (KeyedItem)tNode.getItem();
                            ^
  symbol:   class KeyedItem
  location: class BinarySearchTree
BinarySearchTree.java:221: error: variable right is already defined in method is_Balanced()
        TreeNode right = root.getRight();
                 ^
BinarySearchTree.java:222: error: variable left is already defined in method is_Balanced()
        TreeNode left = root.getLeft();
                 ^
BinarySearchTree.java:224: error: method getHeight in class BinarySearchTree cannot be applied to given types;
        int left_height = getHeight(right);
                          ^
  required: TreeNode
  found: boolean
  reason: actual argument boolean cannot be converted to TreeNode by method invocation conversion
BinarySearchTree.java:225: error: method getHeight in class BinarySearchTree cannot be applied to given types;
        int right_height = getHeight(left);
                           ^
  required: TreeNode
  found: boolean
  reason: actual argument boolean cannot be converted to TreeNode by method invocation conversion
BinarySearchTree.java:284: error: cannot find symbol
         KeyedItem replacementItem = findLeftmost(tNode.getRight());
         ^
  symbol:   class KeyedItem
  location: class BinarySearchTree
BinarySearchTree.java:296: error: cannot find symbol
         return (KeyedItem)tNode.getItem();
                 ^
  symbol:   class KeyedItem
  location: class BinarySearchTree
BinaryTreeIterator.java:11: error: cannot find symbol
      items = new QueueLinked();
                  ^
  symbol:   class QueueLinked
  location: class BinaryTreeIterator
BinaryTreeIterator.java:25: error: cannot find symbol
      catch (QueueException e) 
             ^
  symbol:   class QueueException
  location: class BinaryTreeIterator
BinaryTreeIterator.java:88: error: cannot find symbol
         QueueInterface<TreeNode> q = new QueueLinked<TreeNode>();
         ^
  symbol:   class QueueInterface
  location: class BinaryTreeIterator
BinaryTreeIterator.java:88: error: cannot find symbol
         QueueInterface<TreeNode> q = new QueueLinked<TreeNode>();
                                          ^
  symbol:   class QueueLinked
  location: class BinaryTreeIterator
43 errors
```

Comment: What happens if you remove the quotes?

Comment: When I remove the quotes it gives me `javac .;queue.jar *.java
javac: invalid flag: .
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
-bash: queue.jar: command not found `    I think I may have found the problem. It should be ':' instead of '.;' on mac. I'll try it today.

Comment: And you should have included the -cp flag, but yes, you need change the path separator, good catch ;)

Comment: I think that's what the problem was. Thank you though